# Problem loading packages while deploying an R Shiny app

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I was trying to deploy an R Shiny app that works perfectly when I run it locally. But when I deploy the app, it shows an error message in some of the outputs: "`Error: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.`".

After reading a few threads, I think it has to do with the loading of the packages.

I am using the following packages:

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(ggthemes)
library(shinythemes)
library(r2symbols)
library(caret)
# install.packages("PresenceAbsence")
library(glmnet)
library(tidyverse)
# install.packages("devtools")
```

I got the following warnings while deploying the app from a fresh new session. I'm not particularly clear about what is going wrong (since the app works on my R session). Could you please suggest to me things I should try to get the app work on the server too?

```
  Loading required package: shiny
Warning: package ‘shiny’ was built under R version 3.6.3
Warning: package ‘shinyjs’ was built under R version 3.6.3
You can use shinyjs to call your own JavaScript functions:
    https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/extend

Attaching package: ‘shinyjs’

The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:

    runExample

The following objects are masked from ‘package:methods’:

    removeClass, show

Warning: package ‘DT’ was built under R version 3.6.3

Attaching package: ‘DT’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:shiny’:

    dataTableOutput, renderDataTable

Warning: replacing previous import ‘vctrs::data_frame’ by ‘tibble::data_frame’ when loading ‘dplyr’
Warning: package ‘ggthemes’ was built under R version 3.6.3
Warning: package ‘shinythemes’ was built under R version 3.6.3
Warning: package ‘r2symbols’ was built under R version 3.6.3

Attaching package: ‘r2symbols’

The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:

    sym

Warning: package ‘caret’ was built under R version 3.6.3
Loading required package: lattice
Warning: package ‘lattice’ was built under R version 3.6.3

Attaching package: ‘PresenceAbsence’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:caret’:

    sensitivity, specificity

Warning: package ‘glmnet’ was built under R version 3.6.3
Loading required package: Matrix
Loaded glmnet 4.0-2
Warning: package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 3.6.3
-- Attaching packages -------------------------------------------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.3.0 --
v tibble  3.0.4     v dplyr   1.0.0
v tidyr   1.0.2     v stringr 1.4.0
v readr   1.3.1     v forcats 0.4.0
v purrr   0.3.3     
Warning: package ‘tibble’ was built under R version 3.6.3
Warning: package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.6.3
-- Conflicts ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- tidyverse_conflicts() --
x tidyr::expand()    masks Matrix::expand()
x tidyr::extract()   masks magrittr::extract()
x dplyr::filter()    masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag()       masks stats::lag()
x purrr::lift()      masks caret::lift()
x tidyr::pack()      masks Matrix::pack()
x purrr::set_names() masks magrittr::set_names()
x dplyr::sym()       masks r2symbols::sym(), ggplot2::sym()
x tidyr::unpack()    masks Matrix::unpack()

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6757
```

**More details:**

I also mention my output in the server section that does not show up when deployed to the Shiny server but works when run from the local PC. The `pred_prob_func()` uses a random forest from `caret` package and gets a predicted probability using a random forest model (`ranger`). I'm not even sure that package loading is a problem but I guess so. However, I don't know why it would work on my PC and not on the Shiny server. Problems in versions?

Outputs:

```
  # Heatmap predicted probabilities
  output$Heatmap_predicted_probabilities <- renderPlot({
   
    plot(x=seq(0,1,0.01), y=rep(0,101), main="Heatmap of predicted probabilities", xlab="The square cross symbol represents the predicted probability based on input values on the dashboard", ylab="", xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(-0.1,0.1), yaxt="n", bty="n", pch=15, cex=20, col=hsv(0.05, seq(0,1,length.out = 101), 0.80))
    points(x=pred_prob_func(input_list())$pred_prob, y=0, lwd=2, pch=7, cex=4)
    
  })
```

Comment: You seem to have many conflicts.  Please ensure that you are attaching the package name in front of the function.  For example, you can use `dplyr::filter(...)`, instead of just `filter(...)`.

Comment: @YBS thanks! I have checked and found the sections of the output that are not working when deployed to the Shiny server. I have added them above under "More details".

Comment: I tried to install the newest version of R and now I get an error saying "Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1049338094 failed: Error building image: R version 4.1.2 currently unavailable
Execution halted"

Comment: In your case, you should specify the package you are calling from for the following functions: `sym`, `sensitivity`, `specificity`.  Eg, call as `package::sensitivity`, where `package` is the actual package of interest in your program.  Also, use `DTOutput` and `renderDT`, instead of `dataTableOutput`, `renderDataTable`

Comment: Hi, I just checked that Shiny apps don't support the newest R version yet. So, I went back to using another older version of R.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and I thought I'd post it here for others who may face the same problem in the future. Apparently, it wasn't a problem of versions. When I ran the app with only calling the '`caret`' package it worked fine on my local PC. But it didn't work when uploaded to the Shiny server. I realized it's not enough to call only the '`caret`' package but I also need to call the '`ranger`' library because I was doing a random forest using '`caret`' that used '`ranger`'. Although it works without calling '`ranger`' separately on my local PC, the app only runs smoothly on the server when I add both these lines:

```
library(ranger)
library(caret)
```